# Can't see icons in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, desktop-icons

I have downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 virtually in my Windows 7 host yesterday. Yesterday after installing and rebooting Ubuntu all the icons were visible, but today when I started it today none of the icons in the side panel and in the application launcher are visible. I tried rebooting Ubuntu but still the icons are not visible. I even tried rebooting my host OS (Windows 7), but still no icon. When I am trying to open an application from application launcher it is not opening, but when I am trying to open an app from side panel its opening still with the icon invisible. The background of the desktop is also invisible even after rebooting Ubuntu and Windows. How can I solve this problem???

Comment: You are running Ubuntu on top of Windows 7? How was this configured?

Comment: I didn't get your question. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit pc as the host, VMware workstation player 12 as the medium and Ubuntu 20.04 as my virtual machine.

Comment: Well you answered it VMware.